# youtube api for channel featured content setting

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to set the featured content video through API for 
1. For returning subscribers  
2. For new visitors
I am trying using C#. I was able to add video, create playlist etc. But unable to set the featured content video for the channel.

[Channel Featured content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Eel.jpg)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/  --> here i cannot find any reference for adding the featured content in to youtube channel.

Comment: InvideoTiming invideoTiming = new InvideoTiming();
invideoTiming.OffsetMs = 15000;
invideoTiming.Type = "offsetFromEnd";
PromotedItemId promotedItemId = new PromotedItemId();
promotedItemId.Type = "video";
promotedItemId.VideoId = videoId;
PromotedItem promotedItem = new PromotedItem();  promotedItem.Id = promotedItemId;InvideoPromotion invideoPromotion = new InvideoPromotion();
invideoPromotion.DefaultTiming = invideoTiming;
invideoPromotion.Items = new List<PromotedItem>() { promotedItem };

Comment: Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.Id = videoChannelId;
channel.InvideoPromotion = invideoPromotion; 
ChannelsResource.UpdateRequest _update = youtubeServiceVideo.Channels.Update(channel, "invideoPromotion");
_update.OnBehalfOfContentOwner = contentOwner;
Channel updateChannelResponse = _update.Execute();